# .hgignore for a CakePHP application?

Tags: php, cakephp, mercurial, hgignore

We're using CakePHP for a new application, and we use Mercurial as the source control tool. (Mercurial uses one `.hgignore` file in the root directory, unlike (for example) CVS that uses `.cvsignore` in any directory.)

I'd like to exclude the content of the `app/tmp/` directory from the source control (since they change all the time, and can be regenerated), but I can't add `app/tmp/*` to `.hgignore`, since then the standard directories under `tmp` (`cache`, `logs`, `sessions`, `tests`, and also `cache/models`, `cache/persistent`, ...) would be missing from new clones made by `hg clone`, resulting in errors.

Currently I have in my `hgignore`:

```
app/tmp/logs/*.log
app/tmp/cache/persistent/cake_*
app/tmp/cache/models/cake_*
```

It would be good to have a "standard" one that could be used in all projects. Can someone suggest a complete solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can add

```
syntax: glob
app/tmp/**
```

to your `.hgignore` file and Mercurial will from that point on ignore all files under `app/tmp/` with the **exception** of files tracked by Mercurial. See `hg help patterns` for more about file name patterns.

So if you do

```
% touch app/tmp/cache/.empty
% touch app/tmp/logs/.empty
% hg add app/tmp/cache/.empty
% hg add app/tmp/logs/.empty
```

and make a clone, then the `app/tmp/cache` and `app/tmp/logs` directories *will* be created and new files in those directories will be ignored. I think that is what you want?

This is also useful for tracking something like `$HOME` since you would want to ignore most files by default and only track explicitly added files.

Comment: That is exactly what I do when using CakePHP, but I use Git and not Mercurial. This way the folder structure is maintained but the actual contents of the directories are not saved.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to ignore file in tmp, but not files in certain directories in tmp.  If that's right then I think you can do so using this:

```
syntax: regexp
^tmp/(?!(cache|logs|sessions|test))
```

That says ignore anything that starts with tmp, unless the next part is cache, log, sessions, test.  For these files:

```
.
`-- tmp
    |-- cache
    |   `-- afile
    `-- tmpfile
```

here is the `hg stat` result:

```
$ hg stat
? .hgignore
? tmp/cache/afile
```

I will note, though, that Cake is probably telling you not to put those files into source control based ont heir being in a tmp directory.  Are you sure they're not something htat your build system is supposed to create?  Sessions in particular sound pretty transitory.

Answer (score 0):

In my own checkouts (from SVN), when the site was deployed, the ./tmp/ directory needed to have some specific permissions.

I removed it from version control entirely, and my deployment script created the directories as required.